# executePrepared throws Phalcon\Db\Exception with message Invalid bind type parameter

Tags: php, pdo, phalcon

I'm trying to use \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->executePrepared() with Phalcon (1.2.5 - 1020540)

exectePrepared expects three arguments:

```
public PDOStatement executePrepared (
                PDOStatement $statement, 
                array $placeholders, 
                array $dataTypes)
```

But I can't found in the documentation how to fill $dataTypes.

I try with:

```
   $dataType[] = \PDO::PARAM_INT;
```

and with:

```
   $dataType[] = \Phalcon\Db\Column::TYPE_INTEGER;
```

but with the same 'Invalid bind type parameter' message

the same happens on 1.2.4, I upgrade trying to fix it.

Any suggestion are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually phalcon expects db parameters in the following syntax:

```
array("columnName => ':value:'", 'bind' => array('value' => 'foo'));
```

Did you try

```
array('column_name' => \Phalcon\Db\Column::TYPE_INTEGER);
```

Think this should work as phalcon works internally a lot with keys (e.g. https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/ext/db/adapter/pdo.c search for dataType)

Comment: Perfect! If I use named params instead '?' it works! lots of thanks @dompie

Answer (score 0):

you can also request the PDO-Adapter (eg Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql) for a given table with describeColumns($table) and get back Phalcon\Db\Column's, then you can ask for getBindType()

```
$fields = $this->db->describeColumns($table);
foreach ($fields as &$field) {
    $objectFields[$field->getName()] = $field->getBindType();
}
```